# How to convert data table into SQLite table using RSQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I am very comfortable using R, but I've never used RSQLite or even SQLite, so I have a question on how to best use RSQLite to add data from a data frame in R to an SQLite table.

I understand that I can create tables and add data like so:

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="Test.sqlite")

dbSendQuery(conn = db,  "CREATE TABLE School (SchID INTEGER,
        Location TEXT, Authority TEXT, SchSize TEXT)")

dbSendQuery(conn = db,
            "INSERT INTO School
         VALUES (1, 'urban', 'state', 'medium')")
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
            "INSERT INTO School
         VALUES (2, 'urban', 'independent', 'large')")
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
            "INSERT INTO School
         VALUES (3, 'rural', 'state', 'small')")
```

However, to do multiple INSERT statements like this, I'd need to parse all rows of the data frame using a for loop.  Is it possible to use vectors and a single INSERT to populate the SQLite table with all values from a data frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dbWriteTable` to write the table in one go. Read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html) to see more examples.